# efficient subdomain extraction

Tags: websites, sub-domain, bulk-extractor

I am wondering how we can effectively extract all subdomains of given website? For example, the free hosting websites, I would like to extract all subdomains and see if I can find some subdomains related to our company that's maybe used for phishing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find subdomains of a site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35078/how-can-i-find-subdomains-of-a-site), [how one can find out sub-domains of a domain without brute-force?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204874/how-one-can-find-out-sub-domains-of-a-domain-without-brute-force)